# Color of text changes on parent element when items on the drop down menu are hovered over

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I've seen questions somewhat similar to mine but haven't really run across one that's exactly like mine, I believe-- that or I can't compare the examples well enough cause I'm pretty new to this.

When I hover over an item from the dropdown menu of my navigation, the original hover effect changes.  I could use some help and any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="item1.htm">Item <span>&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Rants</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="item2.htm">Item <span>&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Rants</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="item3.htm">Item <span>&#9660;</span></a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item Database</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item by Location</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="history.htm">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.htm">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS below:

```
#menu-wrapper {
width:970px;
height:30px;
margin:0;
position:relative;
border-top: 1px solid #FFC98C;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFC98C;
margin-top:20px;
z-index: 99;
}
.navbar {
width:970px;
height:30px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
position:absolute;
list-style-type:none;
font-family: 1.05em Raleway, sans-serif;
background-color: #FFF4D6;
}
.navbar li {
height:auto;
width:160px;
float:left;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
margin-left: 1px;
font-family: 1.05em Raleway, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li span {
color:#ffde8c;
font-size:.80em;
}
.navbar a {
padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
color:#b89230;
}
.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
background-color: #b89230;
color:#fff4d6;
}
.navbar li ul {
display:none;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.navbar li:hover ul {
display:block;
}
.navbar li ul li {
background-color: #FFF4D6;
font-size: .95em;
}
.navbar li ul li a {
border-left: 1px solid gray;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
font-size: .95em;
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #D9B558;
color:#fff4d6;
}
```

Here is my fiddle to show you my problem since I probably can't explain it very well: https://jsfiddle.net/Nimara/a8bwqvpe/

If you notice any redundant code or have any other pointers, please feel free to let me know! I've just begun learning web design and would love to know anything that would help me get better.

Thanks again! (wonderful site btw, been using it the last couple of months for all my questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help resolve your issue:

```
.navbar li:hover > a {
    color: #fff4d6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped out a lot.

So the > is the "child combination" or "direct descendant combinator".  I suppose it aids in selecting the a element right below the list hover?

Comment: Yes, this is a child combinator selector that only matches direct descendants and avoids also applying the color style to the sub-menu links in this particular use case.